# x-editable does not allow zero as valid value

Tags: php, jquery, x-editable

I am trying to insert '0' as a value in x-editable, but I keep getting a 400 Bad Request.
I did a var_dump and used the console to debug, but could not figure out where to modify the script to allow '0' as a valid value. Keep in mind that any value other than zero, is valid...

Here's what I have so far:

```
array(3) {
["name"]=>
string(4) "qnty"
["value"]=>
string(1) "0"
["pk"]=>
string(1) "5"
}
```

Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request

**name:qnty
value:0
pk:6**

Comment: Have you tried searching and/or posting in the reported issues on the x-editable github page? https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/issues

Comment: That was one of the places I've first looked. Unfortunately I don't think the creator of that repository monitors the github page--since there are many bug fix requests over 4 months old

Comment: If anyone else has this issue, check your client side validation. This solved my issue.